# Calculate averages if values are in different rows in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d9aca1f9a5b2aaedfa7020d63650d4ba)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int primary key,
    category VARCHAR(255),
    event_date DATE,
    sales_volume VARCHAR(255), 
    return_volume VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(id, category, event_date, 
sales_volume, return_volume
)
VALUES 
("1", "CAT_01", "2018-05-30", "500", NULL),
("2", "CAT_01", "2018-06-05", NULL, "450"),
("3", "CAT_02", "2019-07-08", "700", NULL),
("4", "CAT_02", "2019-07-18", NULL, "670");
```

The table displays the `sales` and `returns` per `category`.

Now I want to calculate the `return_rate` by `returns/sales`. 
The result should look like this:

```
Category      sales_volume      return_volume       return_rate
CAT_01           500               450                0.90
CAT_02           700               670                0.96
```

I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
category,
sales_volume,
return_volume,
return_volume / sales_volume as return_rate
FROM sales;
```

However, when I run this query I get `NULL` for the `return_rate`. 
I assume this issue is casued because the `return_volume` is in a different row than the `sales_volume`.

How do I have to modify my query to get the expected result?

Comment: So, based on that assumption, what's the solution? I'm beginning to think this drip-feeding of answers isn't really providing you a worthwhile learning experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking everything again I figured out that `HeidiSQL` on my computer runs the query through even if it looks like this:

```
SELECT
category,
sales_volume,
return_volume,
sum(return_volume) / sum(sales_volume) as return_rate
FROM sales;
```

The result is this:

```
Category      sales_volume      return_volume       return_rate
CAT_01           0                  0                 0.90
CAT_02           0                  0                 0.96
```

When I run this query in the **[DB - Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d968ca62dcfbc7d20511ae5a70ed1cc0)** it does not get through because the `SUM` for `sales_volume` and `return_volume` as well as the `GROUP BY 1` is missing.

Once I modify my query with it looking like this:

```
SELECT
category,
sum(sales_volume),
sum(return_volume),
sum(return_volume) / sum(sales_volume) as return_rate
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1;
```

I will also get the correct result here **[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=afdd9fe6df482666e2c0f41d706d6d10)**.

Of course the other answers to this question work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce()` to replace `null` values & do aggregation :

```
SELECT category, 
       SUM(coalesce(sales_volume, 0)) AS sales_volume, 
       SUM(coalesce(return_volume, 0)) AS return_volume,
       SUM(coalesce(return_volume, 0)) / SUM(coalesce(sales_volume, 0)) AS return_rate
FROM sales
group by category;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may try below query -

```
SELECT
category,
MAX(sales_volume),
MAX(return_volume),
MAX(return_volume) / MAX(sales_volume) as return_rate
FROM sales
GROUP BY category;
```